# Dynamic stream handling Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, stream

I have a requirement to parse some large CSV files in a folder and process each row in a CSV. I was using a single read stream like following for processing more than 500 CSV files in the directory. I have noticed that after pause/resume stream some CSV stream not ending or its stopped reading data in the middle.

```
stream = fs.createReadStream(filePath)
```

So I thought about dynamically create a stream for each CSV like below, here am getting js 'JavaScript heap out of memory' error. 
I am not sure this is the way to handle multiple files streaming parallelly.

**Can you advise me in following**

1. Can I use a single read stream to handle multiple files, as I am
   calling the read stream function before the earlier stream completes
2. Do I need to handle streams dynamically like below?

.//Parse csv

```
let multipleStream = [];
async function parseCSV(fileName, name) {
  logger.info(`processCSV ${fileName}`);
  let filePath = config.api.basePath + '/test/' + fileName;
  let numConcurrent = 0;
  let paused = false;
  const maxConcurrent = config.api.maxConcurrentJobProcess;
  name = fs.createReadStream(filePath)
      .on('error', (error) => {
        // handle error
        logger.error(`error processing csv`);

        reject(error);

      })
      .pipe(csv())
      .on('data', async (row) => {
        function checkResume() {
          --numConcurrent;
          if ((paused && numConcurrent < maxConcurrent)) {
            name.resume();
            paused = false;
          }
        }

        ++numConcurrent;
        checkResume()
        if (numConcurrent >= maxConcurrent) {
          // pause the stream because we have max number of operations going
          name.pause();
          paused = true;
        }
      })
      .on('end', () => {
        // handle end of CSV
        logger.info(`stream processCSV end ${fileName}`);
      });
  multipleStream.push(name)
}

async function readDirectory() {
  try {
    var counter = 0;
    fs.readdir(config.api.basePath + '/test/', (err, files) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      for (const file of files) {
        counter++;
        console.log('file', file);
        let name = 'a' + counter;
        parseCSV(file, name)
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {

  }
}
readDirectory();
```

Comment: Is reading multiple files simultaneously faster for you?  Why not read one at a time?  I'm trying to remember the details, but I think this `pause()`/`resume()` has side effects for whatever you're piped to, and is also advisory only.  I would pipe one file at a time, unpiping after each file.  Alternatively, you can use the `readable` event and handle it when your code is ready to do so.